# Rufus-scheduler scheduling twice despite using locks

Tags: heroku, rufus-scheduler

I'm well aware why this is happening (two ruby runtimes) and that this is a common problem for people who have not read the RS FAQ or searched on SO for this before, but I've spent a couple days trying many prescribed solutions yet my rufus-scheduler continues to invoke twice.

This occurs on production only, running Rails 5.0.6, Puma server, on Heroku.

This is my scheduler.rb:

```rb
require 'rufus-scheduler'

a_scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new(:lockfile => ".rufus-scheduler-a.lock")
b_scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new(:lockfile => ".rufus-scheduler-b.lock")

unless defined?(Rails::Console) || File.split($0).last == 'rake' || !Rails.env.production?
  a_scheduler.cron '0 21 * * *', overlap: false, blocking: true do
    MySidekiqWorker.perform_async unless a_scheduler.down? 
  end

  b_scheduler.every '1h', overlap: false, blocking: true do
    MyOtherSidekiqWorker.perform_async unless b_scheduler.down?
  end
end
```

I've tried lockfiles, configuring my own scheduler_lock, different parameters for `.every` and `.cron`. Moreover, it seems even though I have `overlap: false` and `blocking: true`, new instances of `MyOtherSidekiqWorker` will still be invoked while one is still running.

I must be missing something obvious, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, [Heroku dynos not sharing the file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26743056/heroku-dynos-not-sharing-the-file-system)

The `.rufus-scheduler-a.lock` seen on dyno d0 is not the `.rufus-scheduler-a.lock` seen on dyno d1.

Your Heroku dynos do not share the same filesystem and also they do not share the same Ruby process and thus not the same rufus-scheduler instance. So `overlap: false`, `blocking: true` will not have any effect from dyno d0 to dyno d1.

You could implement a custom locking mechanism for rufus-scheduler taking inspiration from https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#advanced-lock-schemes (probably via the database because it's shared by your Ruby processes) but that will not help with `overlap: false` and `blocking: true`.

If you still want to have `overlap: false` and `blocking: true`, you could look at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes and have the scheduling happening in a dedicated process/dyno with rufus-scheduler or Clockwork and have no need for a schedule lock.

The rest of my answer is about your code, not about the double scheduling you are experiencing.

**scheduler.down?**

```
b_scheduler.every '1h', overlap: false, blocking: true do
  MyOtherSidekiqWorker.perform_async unless b_scheduler.down?
end
```

Why do you have this `unless b_scheduler.down?` if the `b_scheduler` is down the block will not be executed at all.

This is sufficient:

```
b_scheduler.every '1h', overlap: false, blocking: true do
  MyOtherSidekiqWorker.perform_async
end
```

**a_scheduler vs b_scheduler**

You do not need one scheduler for each job. You can simply write:

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'                                                   

#scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new(lockfile: '.rufus-scheduler.lock')     
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new                                  

unless defined?(Rails::Console) || File.split($0).last == 'rake' || !Rails.env.production?                                                                  
  scheduler.cron '0 21 * * *', overlap: false, blocking: true do            
    MySidekiqWorker.perform_async                                           
  end                                                                       
  scheduler.every '1h', overlap: false, blocking: true do                   
    MyOtherSidekiqWorker.perform_async                                      
  end                                                                       
end
```